# Filter results based on logged in user (Joomla 3.2.2)

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

this is my first post so I hope I have used the correct place.........

If anyone can help with this query I would be most grateful.

I have a data table on my website and need to customise it to display only permitted information based on the access level of the user group the logged in user is assigned to. So this is my current query which shows records made by the current logged in user based on their registered email. So for instance, if I have 5 users in the 'standard' usergroup and they all create a record each, with this query they can each view their own record, what I need is if the user is in the 'advanced' usergroup, they can view their own records plus any created by the users in the 'standard' usergroup. This is on a joomla website, not sure if that makes a difference but all of the access levels are defined by the CMS and I can't have the names of the actual usergroup in the query as there will be many different ones, it needs to find the usergroup based on the email address/ID of the user who is logged in.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN state = '1' THEN 'Accepted' WHEN state = '-2' THEN 'Waiting' WHEN state = '-1' THEN 'Archived' WHEN state = '0' THEN 'Rejected' ELSE 'Unknown' END) AS Status, s.names, s.phone, FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime1,'%d/%m/%y %T'), s.begin, s.PickupAddr1, s.end, s.PickupAddr4, s.message, s.selpassengers, s.selluggage, IF(s.returntrip=0, 'No', 'Yes'), IF(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime2,'%Y') = '1970', NULL, FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime2, '%d/%m/%y %T')), tc.title AS Vehicle, s.cprice, pm.title As Payment, s.payment, s.selinfantseats, s.selchildseats, s.selboosterseats, s.selcarry, s.email, s.id, s.prepay, s.vehicletype FROM #__taxibooking_orders s
INNER JOIN #__taxibooking_cars tc ON tc.id = s.vehicletype
INNER JOIN #__taxibooking_paymentmethods pm ON pm.id = s.payment
WHERE s.email = {$UserEmail}
```

What I need is to modify this so that the records displayed are those created by anyone in a specific user group.

The reference for who created the record is the 'email' field of the 'taxibooking_orders' table
The usergroups are defined in the 'usergroups' table
The users are defined in the 'users' table which also has an 'email' field

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Why don't you just use the standard APIs in Joomla for filtering based on permissions? This is all built into Joomla and all the standard core extensions show you how to do that. Also why would you use the email rather than the user id?   Access levels are designed by the webmaster not by the CMS, the CMS gives you the power to make whatever permissions make sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Joomla 3.2 (yet), but Joomla 2.5 has a table #__user_usergroup_map which maps user ids to usergroup ids. Thus, you'd have to modify the WHERE part like this:

```
WHERE s.email={$UserEmail} AND s.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM #__user_usergroup_map WHERE group_id=<yourgroupid>);
```

=> this is to get the records if the user is in the usergroup. Skip the s.email={$UserEmail} part if you want to do it for any user.

Though I would agree with Elin to use the id instead of the email address in both cases.

Comment: Thanks Elk. I see what you are saying but I cannot define the usergroup in the query as there will be many users groups so would have to create a new instance of the report for each user group which is what I am trying to avoid. I have however found an extension that seems to be able to do exactly what I need so will try it out and see how it goes.